# iOS Firebase detects crashes in Events, but not recognizes the application in the Crashlytics section

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I spent entire day figuring out what's going on with Crashlytics and my app.
It detects fatal events when I crash my app, but not activating crashlytics section for the app.

[Not detecting app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHPb.png)

It's not detecting the app, but it does detect crash events:

[Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzqvD.png)

Here is the log:

```
2021-02-18 19:13:37.616817-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623603] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.6.2
2021-02-18 19:13:37.935629-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id 'a0508fb8c8f14176bd8b3c186ece7e53' for submission
2021-02-18 19:13:38.117774-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:38.118689-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone8,2, 14.4.0 (18D52)
2021-02-18 19:13:38.119240-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Registered Firebase Analytics event listener
2021-02-18 19:13:38.119603-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Automatic data collection is enabled.
2021-02-18 19:13:38.119863-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unsent reports will be uploaded at startup
2021-02-18 19:13:38.120093-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/RemoteConfig][I-RCN000062] Loading database at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41DD1547-68EE-4853-97B2-D24DA38F2CC6/Library/Application Support/Google/RemoteConfig/RemoteConfig.sqlite3
2021-02-18 19:13:38.120430-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF900002] Session Id generated - 382402f1304d45a4a256b540eb2a17f3
2021-02-18 19:13:38.120665-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Preparing the report for the new endpoint: 1
2021-02-18 19:13:38.120972-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2021-02-18 19:13:38.121183-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Expected encodable string, but found NSNull instead. Set a symbolic breakpoint at FIRCLSEncodeString to debug.
2021-02-18 19:13:38.121942-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Sending event.
2021-02-18 19:13:38.122189-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging trace metric - _as 690.5800ms
2021-02-18 19:13:38.122420-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:38.122728-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Completed report submission with id: a0508fb8c8f14176bd8b3c186ece7e53
2021-02-18 19:13:38.129444-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623796] 6.34.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
2021-02-18 19:13:38.130078-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623796] 6.34.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902004] Network status has changed. Code:1, status:Disconnected
2021-02-18 19:13:38.130363-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623796] 6.34.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902004] Network status has changed. Code:2, status:Connected
2021-02-18 19:13:38.130630-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623796] 6.34.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
2021-02-18 19:13:38.169758-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS024000] Debug mode is on
2021-02-18 19:13:38.170176-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at ...
2021-02-18 19:13:38.170548-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001008] Successfully created App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO (Boolean) in the Info.plist
2021-02-18 19:13:38.175850-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2021-02-18 19:13:38.177508-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
2021-02-18 19:13:38.179096-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
2021-02-18 19:13:38.179573-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023207] To enable verbose logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsVerboseLoggingEnabled (see ...)
2021-02-18 19:13:38.180006-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] APMExperimentAlarm scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 6872.976175904274
2021-02-18 19:13:38.180497-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2021-02-18 19:13:38.180973-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS029014] Successfully parsed a configuration. Version: 1613596375523952
2021-02-18 19:13:38.181041-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023016] Analytics is ready to receive events
2021-02-18 19:13:38.187078-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2021-02-18 19:13:38.189051-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Engagement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 3600
2021-02-18 19:13:38.189369-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2021-02-18 19:13:38.189958-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2021-02-18 19:13:38.192536-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: clx, app_exception (_ae), {
    fatal = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = clx;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    timestamp = 0;
}
2021-02-18 19:13:38.192579-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623786] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: app_exception (_ae), {
    fatal = 1;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = clx;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    timestamp = 0;
}
2021-02-18 19:13:38.197688-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623796] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: app_exception (_ae), {
    fatal = 1;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = clx;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    timestamp = 0;
}
2021-02-18 19:13:38.204796-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623790] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 0.7330728769302368
2021-02-18 19:13:39.040080-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623791] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
2021-02-18 19:13:39.040689-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623791] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
2021-02-18 19:13:39.040831-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623791] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: app_exception (_ae), {
    fatal = 1;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = clx;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    timestamp = 0;
}
2021-02-18 19:13:39.265469-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 1115.4450ms
2021-02-18 19:13:39.266737-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:39.266889-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 1115.7930ms
2021-02-18 19:13:39.267039-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:39.268343-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 429
2021-02-18 19:13:39.268571-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 9, 1613693617937
2021-02-18 19:13:39.339025-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623787] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1613693619338, <APMPBMeasurementBatch: 0x282089750>
2021-02-18 19:13:39.588713-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2021-02-18 19:13:39.934109-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623792] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2021-02-18 19:13:40.072404-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://app-measurement.com/a, Response code: 204, 545.4280ms
2021-02-18 19:13:40.072587-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:40.072700-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:13:40.073752-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
2021-02-18 19:13:40.077967-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -1.139809966087341
2021-02-18 19:13:40.086867-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623782] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
2021-02-18 19:14:12.238166-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 61.9940ms
2021-02-18 19:14:12.239045-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:14:12.240757-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 62.8420ms
2021-02-18 19:14:12.241533-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:14:12.242150-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
2021-02-18 19:14:12.242965-0500 Flipper Vanilla[6802:623785] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Installations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
```

My guess it's related to:

```
Expected encodable string, but found NSNull instead. Set a symbolic breakpoint at FIRCLSEncodeString to debug.
```

When I set a breakpoint there, in debugger I see a string, but once the string passed to the FIRCLSEncodeString function it becomes nil

No idea what could cause it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I found what caused it.
My app didn't have display name and string version in the target settings, it caused the Crashlytics to print `Expected encodable string, but found NSNull instead` and eventually not sending the report.
I had to disable all optimizations in order to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for this @igor-kogan, in my case it was the build version that was empty

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where are those settings found?